# libGDX: input processor not working with Group

Tags: libgdx, scene2d

I have a Group which i have added in stage in my screen

```
//Code in show() method of my screen
MyGroup myGroup = new MyGroup(); 
Stage stage = new Stage();
stage.add(myGroup);
//And also there are few more actors which are omitted
Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(stage);

//Code in my group
public MyGroup extends Group implements InputProcessor{
//Many methods and attributes and a constructor
//Overridden methods of input listener.
```

In my group I have 5 actors which can be swapped with one another so, I dont want to handle any input in individual actors. I want to do it in the group.

But none of the methods are being invoked when i touch/touchDrag.

Please help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because your `MyGroup` is not registered as a currently active `InputProcessor`. You would need to use an `InputMultiplexer` to register both the `Stage` and your `Group`.

```
InputMultiplexer inputMultiplexer = new InputMultiplexer();
inputMultiplexer.addProcessor(stage);
inputMultiplexer.addProcessor(myGroup);
Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(inputMultiplexer);
```

Comment: Now i am facing one more issue. That is, the touch co-ordinates I am getting from touchDragged event is mirrored over X-axis. Any idea why is this happening ?

Comment: Well, those coordinates are screen space coordinates. The stage and actors have special methods to convert the coordinates to the different coordinate systems. For example screenToStage, or stageToLocal.

Comment: Thanks @noone. I used camera.unProject. Will try screenToStage and stageToLocal